# How to split a QList at position n to a new QList

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

is there a simple method to copy a `QList<Class*>` from position a to b in a new QList?

I tested:

```
  QList<Class*> newList(list.begin()+5,list.end());
```

but it doesn't work. I get the error: "No matching call...."

can someone help me?

Greetings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
QList<Class*> newList(list.mid(0,5));
```